# service bus message is not process properly got exception still didn't go into dead letter?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have azure function which trigger when new message is there into service bus topic.

```
[FunctionName("processData")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("customer", "customer", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {


                // get the first bearer token 
                var access_token = GetBearerToken();

                // call API
                var APIresponse = APICall("APIURL", access_token, log);

                // if api response status code is OK 200 then process the message
                if (APIresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // for testing 
                }
                else
                {
                 // how to abandon message here
                }

                //log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info($"Exception: {ex}");
            }
        }
```

But irrespective of anything message count is becoming `0` in subscription after above code execution..

How to control message processing ? How can we use `Abandon` when any exception occurs so that message go into Dead letter...

I tried to add `new throw Exception('test')` in between code but it goes into catch and still no message forwarded into dead letter.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, your function need to throw an exception for it to be considered a failure. Currently you're handling the exception which makes the function run as successful.

Can you try by changing the `catch` block to:

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Info($"Exception: {ex}");
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: oh got it what about a use of `Abandon` ? what you suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know about the effect of calling Abandon on message. I would let someone else comment on that.

Answer (score 3):

> How can we use Abandon when any exception occurs so that message go into Dead letter

Every-time you abandon a message, delivery count will be increased by 1. And when it reaches to max delivery count ([which is 10 default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#exceeding-maxdeliverycount)), it will be sent to dead-letter queue.

Abandon affects just the one where it was abandoned, and dead letter queues are separate.

One caveat is that if you want to resubmit messages from dead-letter queue, you can't send them directly to the corresponding subscription, it has to go through the topic again.

**Edit**:

In your application, whenever an exception occurs during processing you want to reprocess the message again. For this, we have the facility of AbandonAsync.

AbandonAsync abandons a Message using a lock token, this will make the message available again for processing.

To verify this we need to throw an exception explicitly from ReceiveMessageAsync and from the catch block call AbandonAsync method.

```
static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");  
        int i = 0;  
        i=i / Convert.ToInt32(message);  
        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);  
     }  
     catch(Exception ex)  
     {  
         await queueClient.AbandonAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);  
     }  
 }
```

For more details, refer to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-service-bus-queue-with-real-world-scenario/).

Comment: ok got your point how to abandon that message in else condition if api status is not 200? could you please give a code snippet here?

Answer (score 0):

if your function is a version 2, you can move a message to the deadletter sub-queue directly, see the following example:

```
    [FunctionName("processData")]
    public static void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("customer", "customer", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string mySbMsg, string lockToken, MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
        ILogger log)
    {
         log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");

        // ...

        await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(lockToken);

        // await messageReceiver.AbandonAsync(lockToken);
        // await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(lockToken);
        // await messageReceiver.DeferAsync(lockToken);

        // ...
    }
```